# Show/hide exact div on click?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have  this list of icons:

```
 <ul>
      <li [ngClass]="iconM ? 'active': 'notactive'" title="Kontakti"><span (click)="showHide = !showHide"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>   </li>
      <li [ngClass]="iconD ? 'active': 'notactive'" title="Adrese"><span  (click)="showHide = !showHide"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i><i  class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></li>
      <li [ngClass]="iconW ? 'active': 'notactive'" title="Primaoci računa"><span (click)="showHide = !showHide"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></li>
 </ul>
```

And i have divs:

```
 <div *ngIf="showHide">
  a
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="showHide">
   b
  </div>
 <div *ngIf="showHide">
   c
  </div>
```

Now what i want when user click on first li to show first div, if user click on second li to show second div and so. Do i need 3 boolean variable or ? Because i will have more of this `ul li` on page and more div to hide/show. If i need for every different boolean variable i will a lot of them. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: what is the exact expectation can you reproduce using a plunker using this [**link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KqAbwY7FOaQlvW8Txxxj?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `showHide` object in your component:

```
const showHide = {};
```

Then, for your list elements, set the values as follows (removed irrelevant attributes):

```
<ul>
    <li title="Kontakti">
        <span (click)="showHide['contacts'] = !showHide['contacts']">...</span>
    </li>
    <li title="Adrese">
        <span (click)="showHide['addresses'] = !showHide['addresses']">...</span>
    </li>
    <li title="Primaoci računa">
        <span (click)="showHide['recipients'] = !showHide['recipients']">...</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then for your divs:

```
<div *ngIf="showHide['contacts']"></div>
<div *ngIf="showHide['addresses']"></div>
<div *ngIf="showHide['recipients']"></div>
```

**Update**

In case you want only one div to be open at a time, you can define `show` as a string variable. In that case:

```
const show = null;
```

Then, for your list elements, set the values as follows (removed irrelevant attributes):

```
<ul>
    <li title="Kontakti">
        <span (click)="show = 'contacts'">...</span>
    </li>
    <li title="Adrese">
        <span (click)="show = 'addresses'">...</span>
    </li>
    <li title="Primaoci računa">
        <span (click)="show = 'recipients'">...</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then for your divs:

```
<div *ngIf="show === 'contacts'"></div>
<div *ngIf="show === 'addresses'"></div>
<div *ngIf="show === 'recipients'"></div>
```

Comment: when i click first li its okay, but when i click on second it show me data from first and second div, and then when i click on third li it show me data from fist second and third div

Comment: You want only one to be open at a time?

Comment: Even simpler. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays :

```
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of anyArray; let i = index;" [ngClass]="iconM ? 'active': 'notactive'" title="Kontakti"><span (click)="showHide[i] = !showHide[i]"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>   </li>
</ul>

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of anyArray; let i = index;">
    <div *ngIf="showHide[i]"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying on Angular 1.X version. Please mention the output you want in which version. some of them answering on Angular 2. that is not useful for you.

Check the output here 
 [Plunkr output for your requirement](https://plnkr.co/edit/CteOdtpDpQ85700C4olC)

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <ul><li ng-repeat="li in li" ng-click="clickmthd($index)">{{li}}</li></ul>
    <div ng-repeat="div in div" ng-if="$index == active">Div is {{div}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
`

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.li =[1,2,3];
   $scope.div =[1,2,3];

   $scope.clickmthd = function(index){
     $scope.active = index;
   }
});
```

Comment: No, it's not Angular 1.X (which is now called "AngularJS").